# Django REST Framework pagination not working on remote server

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have implemented "PageNumber" Pagination in Django Rest framework which is working fine locally. But the same code deployed on remote server not returning results with pagination.

Pagination Class:

```
class MyPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 20
```

View using Pagination:

```
class GetMyListings(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.MyListingSerializer
    pagination_class = utils.MyPagination
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    )

    def get_queryset(self):
        order_by_clause = self.request.GET.get('order_by', '-posted_on')
        posted_clause = self.request.GET.get('posted', None)
        if posted_clause:
            return models.Post.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user,
                                              is_posted=utils.make_boolean(posted_clause)
                                              ).order_by(order_by_clause)
        return models.Post.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).order_by(order_by_clause)
```

Comment: give some extra information about versions (e.g. local version of DRF vs the remote one, also for Django, etc.)

Comment: @Marius Thank you, there was difference in versions of Rest Framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Resolved, DRF's local version was `3.3.2` where as server had `3.1.0` because the Custom Django Paginator in `PageNumberPagination` is allowed in version `3.3.2` or later.

For reference, see Release notes:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#332

Comment: Good to hear. Add the difference on behavior between the versions , if you don't mind, just in case it becomes useful for other users.